# How can we calculate transfer funtion of multistage bjt oscillator circuit

Tags: oscillator, transfer-function, feedback

I have been working on a circuit consists of 2 stage CE and class B amplifier network oscillator circuit. For transfer function shall each stage be calculated separately if how? Additionally how can it be done in simulation?(transfer function, oscillator parameters etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question appears to be (rephrased or paraphrased) *how can I be a modern electronics engineer*. Additionally, if there is something about your circuit that concerns you, you should post a schematic.

Comment: What I meant to ask was in an oscillator circuit how can I calculate open/closed loop gain since there is no input voltage? I

Comment: You can break the feedback at any point and treat it like a gain stage. Or read my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/477367/how-is-the-closed-loop-transfer-function-defined-for-an-oscillator).

Comment: It's a critically stable closed loop system. You need to identify the forward path; the feedback path; where the summing junction is, and then draw the block diagram. The input signal can be shown on the diagram, but this will be zero, nevertheless, including it will allow you to derive a transfer function.